# Show only the n'th ticklabel in a pandas boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am new to pandas and matplotlib, but not to Python. I have two questions; a primary and a secondary one.

**Primary:**
I have a pandas boxplot with FICO score on the x-axis and interest rate on the y-axis.
My x-axis is all messed up since the FICO scores are overwriting each other.
I'd like to show only every 4th or 5th ticklabel on the x-axis for a couple of reasons:

- in general it's less chart-junky
- in this case it will allow the labels to actually be read.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
plt.figure()  
loansmin = pd.read_csv('../datasets/loanf.csv')  
p = loansmin.boxplot('Interest.Rate','FICO.Score')
```

I saved the return value in `p` as I thought I might need to manipulate the plot further which I do now.

**Secondary:**
How do I access the plot, subplot, axes objects from pandas boxplot.
`p` above is an `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot` object.
`help(matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot)` gives a message saying:

```
'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AxesSubplot'
```

`dir(matplotlib.axes)` lists `Axes`, `Subplot` and `Subplotbase` as in that namespace but no `AxesSubplot`.  How do I understand this returned object better?

Comment: You should check out the [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=multiplelocator#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) from matplotlib. Here's an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html) concerning this. On a side note; plotting with matplotlib is more flexible than plotting in pandas, in my experience.

Comment: Hi nordev, thanks for the pointer. However to use MultipleLocator I need to get access to the underlying object.  While matplotlib is certainly more flexible, the learning curve is much higher and from my exploration - creating a boxplot was not as simple and transparent as in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AxesSubplot` (I think) is just another way to get at the `Axes` in matplotlib. `set_xticklabels()` is part of the matplotlib object oriented interface (on axes). So, if you were using something like pylab, you might use `xticks(ticks, labels)`, but instead here you have to separate it into different calls `ax.set_xticks(ticks)`, `ax.set_xticklabels(labels)`. (where `ax` is an `Axes` object).

Let's say you only want to set ticks at 650 and 700. You could do the following:

```
ticks = labels = [650, 700]
plt.figure()
loansmin = pd.read_csv('../datasets/loanf.csv')
p=loansmin.boxplot('Interest.Rate','FICO.Score')
p.set_xticks(ticks)
p.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Similarly, you can use `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` to do the equivalent of `xlim()` and `ylim()` in `plt`.

Answer (score 2):

As I explored further I found that one could explore the returned object `p` via `dir()`.
Doing this I found a long list of useful methods, amongst which was `set_xticklabels`.
Doing `help(p.set_xticklabels)` gave some cryptic, but still useful, help - essentially suggesting passing in a list of strings for ticklabels.

I then tried doing the following - adding `set_xticklabels` to the end of the last line in the above code effectively chaining the invocations.

```
plt.figure()  
loansmin = pd.read_csv('../datasets/loanf.csv')  
p=loansmin.boxplot('Interest.Rate','FICO.Score').set_xticklabels(['650','','','','','700'])
```

This gave the desired result.  I suspect there's a better way as in the way matplotlib does it which allows you to show every n'th label.  But for immediate use this works, and also allows setting labels where they are not periodic for whatever reason, if you need that.

As usual, writing out the question explicitly helped me find the answer. And if anyone can help me get to the underlying matplotlib object that is still an open question.

Comment: @Nitlin check out my answer for some explanation about what you found.